# Finding the index row numbers of all common dates between two columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of 2 dataframes that I have imported via excel. Basically, I have a list of dates and stock prices which are different for both of these dataframes (one starts in 1990, the other in 2007). I want to find the common dates between both of these dataframes and concatenate so that I have one column of dates and the appropriate stock prices from dataframe 1 and 2.

```
ff = pd.read_excel('Europe_5_Factors_Daily.xlsx',sheet_name='Factors')
pp = pd.read_excel('Europe_5_Factors_Daily.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1')
ff =ff.iloc[:,0:4]
idx = ff['Date'].reset_index(drop=True) == pp["Date"].reset_index(drop=True).tolist()
print(idx)
```

I get the following error message : ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (8132,), (3457,)). Does anyone know what went wrong here?
Essentially, I'm trying to find the index row numbers of the common dates so that I can then get the equivalent rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

ff = pd.read_excel('Europe_5_Factors_Daily.xlsx',sheet_name='Factors')
pp = pd.read_excel('Europe_5_Factors_Daily.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1')

def find_common_dates(df1,df2):
    df1_dates = df1['Date'].tolist()
    df2_dates = df2['Date'].tolist()
    common_dates = list(set(df1_dates) & set(df2_dates))
    return common_dates
```

Then run

```
find_common_dates(ff,pp)
```